# How to convert a table containing values and frequency to a single list in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with Value in column one Frequency in column two.  The following is the beginning of my list:
[image]

I would like to complete an operation that turns this into a single column with the number for each value corresponding to the frequency.  In this example, the single column would be "-3, 1, 1, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 13, ..., 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D2, formula copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(ROW(A1),SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B$1,,,ROW($1:$17)))+1,A$2:A$16)&""
```

[image]